# AVX2 instruction to combine first and third elements of two packed doubles

Tags: c, vectorization, avx, avx2

I have two AVX2 256 bit registers (i.e. __m256d) that store doubles. The first stores 0 1 2 3 and the other stores 4 5 6 7. I would like to get 0 2 4 6, i.e. combine the first and third elements of each register and store them in a __m256d. Is there any instruction to achieve this directly? If not, what is the fastest way to get the desired result?
Thank you for your help

Comment: Try one `vunpcklpd` followed by a `vpermpd` (with the correct permutation)

Comment: But in this case  `vpermpd` will do lane crossing permutation right?

Comment: Some lane crossing is unavoidable, 2 and 4 end up in opposite lanes of where they started

Comment: You'd need AVX512 `vpermt2pd` to do it in a single shuffle.  If your data is coming from memory anyway, you could offset one of the loads to set up for blend + `vpermpd`, i.e. blend instead of `vuncpklpd`.  But if these are results of other computations, then yeah 2 shuffles (one of them lane-crossing) if you need that specific order.  `vshufpd` can't work because it isn't lane crossing, it can only emulate `vunpcklpd`, `vpalignr` is also not useful, and there really aren't many 2-input shuffles to choose from.

Comment: Yeah chtz's solution worked for me. But thanks @Peter Cordes.

Comment: Yeah, vunpcklpd + vpermd is the best choice when both your inputs are coming from other computations, not loads from memory, like I said.  However, if you *are* loading one of the inputs from memory, and can offset by one double, it might (or might not) be worth using blend+permute if execution port 5 is a bottleneck in the whole loop that includes this code.